# How can I read the data(e.g: torque) from Kuka iiwa robot and write the data(e.g: torque) to Kuka robot?

Tags: ros, kuka-krl, lbr-iiwa-rapi

How can I read the data(e.g: torque) from Kuka iiwa robot and write the data(e.g: torque) to Kuka robot? I have heard that I should use Ethercat not ethernet. Can anybody explain to me how I can do this?

Comment: you tagged this with `robotfamework`, which refers to robotframework.org. Are you asking about the testing framework written in python?

Comment: THanks for the reply. I am asking about the fast robot interface kuka(FRI) with C++. How can I set the torque values to the kuka robot? Sorry, I possibly tagged wrong.

Comment: This might be a better question for the KUKA Robot forum.

https://www.robot-forum.com/robotforum/board/37-kuka-robot-forum/

That allows for better back-and-forth conversation than Stack Overflow and might grab the attention of a more advanced kuka user. I believe Stack Overflow is great, but not strong with having a "conversation" about more complicated topics.